# Left click not working on various places

Tags: windows, mouse

I am experiencing a very weird behaviour since I installed 2.9.3 although I' m not sure this has something to do with the version per se as the same behavior started happening with previous versions as well (I installed up to 2.8 just to make sure).

My mouse's left click does not seem to work at a ton of places. I' m not talking about object selection here, but pretty much everything else. I can't select items from Scene collection, can't drag node connections, can't drag nodes in the Node Editor...

I have no clue why is this happening, played a bit with the settings and googled but can't find anyone else having this problem. Seems to me it might have something to do with maybe a new Windows weird feature more that blender but what's even weirder is that after googling I couldn't find anyone else facing this problem in the past month.

If anyone has any ideas they are welcome, since this renders blender unusable for me :/

Update: I installed 2.79 just to check and it's not working there either so I suspect this has something to do with windows. Again if anyone has any pointers they are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution 10 minutes after I posted the question,

I had an old SCP utility to connect my ps4 controller to my pc that I had even forgotten about and apparently it was interfering with Blender. I will leave it here in case anyone else faces this weird problem in the future.